# Whom do these Viennese sculptures depict?

Tags: architecture, vienna

In Vienna‘s first quarter, on the corner between Universitätsstraße and  Reichsratsstraße, very close to the Votiv Church, there is a building with these sculptures:
[image]
[image]

The first one looks kind of Greek, though I don’t find anyone with whom to identify him with any certainty.

The spot seems pretty well known. I see tourists taking pictures every day, but so far none has been able to tell me, who they are.

Judging from questions about Koxinga, etc. this should be on topic.

Comment: can you be more specific where this building is? Closest to the Votiv Kirche on the eastern side of the street is the backside of the main building of the university of Vienna. So greek might be a good guess

Comment: It is precisely the side closest to the VotivKirche and to the Cafe Votiv. It is the corner between Universitätsstraße (continuation of Alser Straße) and Reichsratstraße.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the backside of the main building of the university of Vienna. The sculptures depict EMPEDOCLES (first pic) and Pythagoras (second pic). For more information on other statues on the building and inside (go inside and explore the Arkadenhof, it is public and beautiful!) see

https://statues.vanderkrogt.net/object.php?webpage=ST&record=atwi152

or the Wikipedia page of the University, which explains all the statues on the inside (they depict scientists etc., wikipedia in german)

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptgeb%C3%A4ude_der_Universit%C3%A4t_Wien

Comment: Yes, I did not order them correctly, I edited my answer